# Copy rename move files powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

After a short period of time I managed to create a script that copies from one server to another, after that it renames it with date and time and then it should move the files to another location. 
I keep getting an error, and I am not entirely sure what is happening

```
$server2 = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\A\"  # UNC Path. 
$datetime = Get-Date -Format "MMddyyyy-HHmmss"
$server3 = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\C\" # UNC Path. 
foreach ($server1 in gci $server1  -recurse)
 { 
     Copy-Item -Path $server1.FullName -Destination $server2
 }

 ForEach ( $server2 in $server2 ) {
    $curDateTime = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HHmmss
    Get-ChildItem $server2  -Recurse | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename + '_' + $curDateTime + $_.Extension }
   }

foreach ($server2 in gci $server2 -Recurse)
 { 
     Move-Item -path $server2 -destination "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\C"
 }
```

error is " 
Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\test.csv_20200513-132035.xlsx' because it does not exist.
At line:17 char:6
 +      Move-Item -path $server2 -destination "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu ..."

Any ideas?

Comment: Add `-whatif` switch to `Move-Item` and `Rename-Item` and study carfully the paths.

Comment: Your script references `$server1`, but it's never declared.

Comment: You cannot do things like `foreach ($server2 in $server2)`. The right-hand-side variable should be a collection of things while the left-hand-side variable is the single 'thing' from that collection you intend to do stuff on. Learn about looping with the `foreach(..)` statement and compare that to the `ForEach-Object {..}` cmdlet, for instance from [here](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-foreach/)

Comment: @Theo, Powershell running in non-strict/non-constrained mode seems to tolerate that, but I agree that it's a terrible practice.

Comment: Also, `"C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\A\"` is **NOT** a UNC path

Comment: ok, so I didn't copy/paste everything properly. I had the item declared, the $server1 , also in that foreach loop it was pointless to keep it as i was going through anyway, also powershell does tolerate that, that wasn't really the issue.. @Theo I kept saying UNC path, but the test was made on a local machine therefore I just commented the lines, where the servers were declared.